# How to method chain .agg() and .assign() functions in Pandas

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation, method-chaining

I am looking to replicate this Dplyr query in Pandas but am having trouble chaining the the **.agg()** and **.assign()** functions together, and would be so grateful for any advice

**Dplyr** code:

```
counties_selected %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarize(total_area = sum(land_area),
            total_population = sum(population)) %>%
  mutate(density = total_population / total_area) %>%
  arrange(desc(density))
```

Attempt at the same in **Pandas**:
Within the .assign() part I am redirecting the variable back into the original dataframe, but nothing else works

```
counties.\
   groupby('state').\
   agg(total_area = ('land_area', 'sum'),
       total_population = ('population', 'sum')).\
   reset_index().\
   assign(density = counties['total_population'] / counties['total_area']).\
   arrange('density', ascending = False).\
   head()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), it is easy to port your dplyr code to python code, without learning pandas APIs:

```py
from datar.all import f, group_by, summarize, sum, mutate, arrange, desc

counties_selected >> \
  group_by(f.state) >> \
  summarize(total_area = sum(f.land_area),
            total_population = sum(f.population)) >> \
  mutate(density = f.total_population / f.total_area) >> \
  arrange(desc(f.density))
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you need `lambda` for processing chained data, alreday processing in previous chained methods:

```
assign(density = counties['total_population'] / counties['total_area'])
```

to:

```
assign(density = lambda x: x['total_population'] / x['total_area'])
```

Another problem is for sorting is used instead:

```
arrange('density', ascending = False)
```

method [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
sort_values('density', ascending = False):
```

All together, `.` is used to start of methods like:

```
df = (counties.groupby('state')
              .agg(total_area = ('land_area', 'sum'),
                   total_population = ('population', 'sum'))
              .reset_index()
              .assign(density = lambda x: x['total_population'] / x['total_area'])
              .sort_values('density', ascending = False)
              .head())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding and sharing your knowledge, it works perfectly, but is there a way also to chain the .arrange() portion through too? it doesnt seem to pick up the new variable 'density'.

Comment: @RobertChestnutt - Sorry, I miss it, answer was edited.